# Check for PNR existence from JS in a web RedApp

Tags: sabre

We are creating a web RedApp from SabreRedWorkspace and we need to check for the existence of a valid PNR before adding some passive segments.

We need to do it from an Angular app, and we can't find ant doc or example about it. Everything talks about RestAPI or the new NativeAPI and we can't find anything about web RedApps

Any help? Someone could point us to any doc or example?

Comment: The APIs are the same in all cases. In fact, for advanced functionality you'll have to use the SOAP APIs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you think there is no way to do it using the ```SrwApi```object injected in the DOM by the SRW? Have I to call an external SOAP API server to retrieve the local workspace information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript API for that, using SrwApi3.retrievePnr("1.0.0") which is injected on the DOM for Web RedApps.
Please make sure to download the latest SDK from https://beta.developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/sdks/sabre-red-360-resources, version 19.5, there where changes on this release exactly about "Get PNR" APIs.
For more documentation, you can check on the SDK documentation folder : [extracted dir]/red-app-sdk-3.0-19.5/documentation/htmls/get_pnr_(web_api).html, ob by navigating from index->New Sabre Red Workspace Developer Toolkit->Sabre Services 3.0, Get PNR (Web API)
Also theres sample code provided on SDK, look for the compressed project under samples folder : com.sabre.redapp.example.webkit-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-v20190516-1622.zip